# C. I need put inside a bidimensional char array, but out of the loop the result is every the last data

Tags: arrays, c, while-loop

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char *string[2][5], trunkcode[50];

    while (i <= 1)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            strcpy(trunkcode,"test0");
        else if(i == 1)
            strcpy(trunkcode,"test1");
        
        string[i][0] = trunkcode;
        printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[i][0]);

        ++i;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[0][0]);
    printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[1][0]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

output:

trunkcode test0
trunkcode test1

trunkcode test1
trunkcode test1

Why the output is not

trunkcode test0
trunkcode test1

trunkcode test0
trunkcode test1

Comment: Because there's only one `trunkcode` array. The assignments to the `string` array **do not** make copies of the string in `trunkcode`.

Comment: @Adilson Magnus This declaration  char *string[2][5] does not make sense.

Comment: I'm have select from my database and need put the SELECT result inside a array. Like php.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one `trunkcode` array. Both `string[0][0]` and `string[1][0]` contain pointers to that same array. You replace the contents of the array with the `strcpy()` codes, so at the end of the loop the array contains `test1`, and both pointers point to that content.

You don't need the `trunkcode` array. Just make `string` a 2-dimensional array of characters rather than pointers.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    char string[2][50];

    while (i <= 1)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            strcpy(string[i],"test0");
        else if(i == 1)
            strcpy(string[i],"test1");
        
        printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[i]);

        ++i;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[0]);
    printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[1]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tanks for you help. But in my real case trunk code is a array.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what is happening in your program,
(as commented in code below),

```
int main(void)
{
    int i = 0;

   char *string[2][5], trunkcode[50];

    while (i <= 1)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            strcpy(trunkcode,"test0"); //  truncode would contain test0 when i = 0
        else if(i == 1)
            strcpy(trunkcode,"test1"); // truncode would contain test1 when i = 1

        string[i][0] = trunkcode; // points to value stored in truncode
        printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[i][0]); // test0 is printed at i = 0 and test1 at i = 1
        // above line prints whatever string[i][0] points to, which is  'current value' of truncode.

        ++i;
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[0][0]); // string[0][0] now points to last value of truncode (test1)
    printf("trunkcode %s\n",string[1][0]); // string [1][1] also points to last value of truncode (test1)

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you are correctly, but how I can add the test1 string inset the string[1][0] and printf string[1][0] out the while loop and print test1?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that what you wrote is not what you want.

You had string declared as:

```
    char *string[2][5];
```

and maybe clearer to write

```
    char*        string[2][5];
```

When you write this way it gets clear what is `string`: an array of 2x5 pointers to `char`. Just pointers. And as so you have to allocate memory for any of the 10 pointers before use, or point them to something already allocated.

And you have

```
    char trunkcode[50];
```

A 50-char array. And it is the only allocated `char` in your code. It can contain only one value at a time, from `trunkcode[0]` to `trunkcode[49]`, up to 50 `char`.

```
    string[i][0] = trunkcode; // points to value stored in truncode
```

To write it in the comments does not make it true. `trunkcode` is `char[50]` `string[][]` is `char*`. This assignment makes `string[i][0]` points to the address of `trunkcode`, `&trunkcode[0]` you could write, or just `trunkcode`.

When you change `trunkcode` via `strcpy()` you change what `string[0][0]` points to. And also what `string[1][0]` points to, since both points to `trunkcode`

Comment: Do you understand now that `string` in your program is an array of 10 pointers to `char`? Are you just trying to SELECT from a db some strings as _trunkcodes_ and put into an array? Two separate SELECT maybe?